# binding datasource using javascript in devexpress

Tags: devexpress

I have two dropdown list named companyID and deparmentID, and both are bind using sqldatasource. departmentID dropwdown is bind with SQLdatasource that would generate list whenever companyId is selected. I can do this when using selectedindexchanged method of companyId and setting its autopostback to true. But I don't want to use that method. Is there a way that I can rebind the datasource of departmendID using javascript or jquery of DEVEXPRESS? Hope someone can help me with this.

```
     protected void cmbCompany_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DeptSQL.DataBind();
        }

This is my mark up code for my combo box:

    <dx:LayoutItem Caption="Company" ColSpan="2" Width="100%">
                                <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                                    <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer runat="server">
                                        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbCompany" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="CompSQL" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbCompany_SelectedIndexChanged" TextField="MDRF_CompDesc" ValueField="MDRF_CompId">
                                        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CompSQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MDRFConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [MDRF_CompId], [MDRF_CompShort], [MDRF_CompDesc] FROM [MDRF_Company] ORDER BY [MDRF_CompDesc]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                                <CaptionSettings HorizontalAlign="Left" Location="Top" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            </dx:LayoutItem>
                            <dx:LayoutItem Caption="Department" Width="100%">
                                <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                                    <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer runat="server">
                                        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbDepartment" runat="server" DataSourceID="DeptSQL" TextField="MDRF_DepDesc" ValueField="MDRF_DepId" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DeptSQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MDRFConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [MDRF_DepDesc], [MDRF_DepId], [MDRF_Comp] FROM [MDRF_Department] WHERE ([MDRF_Comp] = @MDRF_Comp)">
                                            <SelectParameters>
                                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cmbCompany" Name="MDRF_Comp" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
                                            </SelectParameters>
                                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                                <CaptionSettings HorizontalAlign="Left" Location="Top" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            </dx:LayoutItem>
```

Is there a way to call that in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Are you want to implement "cascading combobox" like [this example](https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ASPxComboBox/ClientAPI.aspx)? Please include the markup to show your `ComboBox` and `SqlDataSource` control settings.

Comment: yes that is what i needed.. This is my mark up. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I concerned about "rebind the datasource using JS/jQuery" for second dropdown - rebinding requires postback to server and `AutoPostBack="True"` serves that purpose. Are you want to perform AJAX postback and return option lists into second `ASPxComboBox` instead of standard postback?

Comment: yes. but I don't want that approach as it will blink the page which is so irritating in the eyes. Yes I want to perform ajax postback, that is exactly what i need.